# Early stopping Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

as the Title suggest is there anyway to implement early stopping on the TF object detection API?

i read in this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5887 on the github of Object detection that there's a repo https://github.com/hongym7/early_stopping for early stopping. but this is an older version of TF1 and i use TF2

is there any way to implement early stopping on the `model_main_tf2.py` ? i've spent few hours reading the codes but i don't see any place to implement the early stopping.

Here's the link to the script to train the model
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it in `tf.keras` and use `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping` . Read https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping for more detail